# How tall were Hagrid's parents?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

In the book Goblet of Fire, Hagrid claims that when he was 6 he could pick his dad up and put him in a dresser, and how tall his mom was, I have not the slightest clue. Does JK Rowling give any estimations or exact heights for Hagrid's parents?

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: there is no info on her specific height. But there's info on giants in general

Comment: i see ill just assume his father was a mini dwarf and his mom was Andre the giants size would that be accurate enough?

Comment: @Fingolfin no no. His mother was an actual Giant, not just giant sized. His half brother Grawp (who is full giant) would be of similar size as his mother.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can give you a tiny bit more info. We know that Grawp - Hagrid's brother - is quite small:

> See, with giantesses, what counts is producin' good big kids, and he's always been on a bit on the runty side fer a giant - on'y sixteen foot -'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.609 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 30, *Grawp*

So it's not unreasonable to surmise that Fridwulfa (Hagrid's mother) may have been a relatively short giant, with the giants Hagrid saw being 20-25 feet:

> 'How big are they?' asked Ron in a hushed voice.
>
> ''Bout twenty feet,' said Hagrid casually. 'Some o' the bigger ones mighta bin twenty-five.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.377 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 20, *Hagrid's Tale*

As for Hagrid's dad, I can say in addition that when Hagrid was about seven or eight feet tall, his father was short enough to sit on his shoulder:

> Hagrid got up, went over to his dresser, opened a drawer and pulled out a picture of a short wizard with Hagrid's crinkled black eyes, beaming as he sat on top of Hagrid's shoulder. Hagrid was a good seven or eight feet tall, judging by the apple tree beside him, but his face was beardless, young, round and smooth - he looked hardly older than eleven.
>
> 'Tha' was taken jus' after I got inter Hogwarts,' said Hagrid, croakily.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - p.395 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 24, *Rita Skeeter's Scoop*

Answer (score 12):

Hagrid's mother was a giant, whose average height is considered to be ~20 feet tall according to Hermione GoF:

> 'Well, I thought he must be,' she said, shrugging. 'I knew he couldn't be pure giant, because they're about twenty feet tall.

We don't know anything about the father's height aside from GoF quote you mention:

> **Tiny little bloke, my dad was**. By the time I was six I could lift him up an' put him on top o' the dresser if he annoyed me

There's really no more info, on Pottermore or any interviews.

Comment: That makes the thought about him being conceived quite disturbing...

Comment: We are talking about a childen's book series that starts with a cold blooded murder of two adults and an attempted murder of a 1 year old child; followed by long term child abuse in a foster home. I'm not sure JKR has issues with "disturbing".

Comment: The "Tiny little bloke" line might only be relative to Hagrid's size at the time. The dad might have been normal human size and just seemed small to Hagrid.

Comment: @Yasskier http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HotSkittyOnWailordAction

Comment: Just a thought, is it canon in the book that Madame Maxime is taller than Hagrid or is she about the same height? If she's taller, that would give weight to the above theory that Hagrid's mother may have been on the short side.

Comment: @Pwassonne I had that thought! In the Goblet of Fire, it says that Harry doubted there was an inch difference in their heights, but that she somehow seemed even bigger to Harry, perhaps because he was used to Hagrid. I had a quick flick through and could not then find any reference suggesting Hagrid was shorter than her in scenes where they're together. It seems reasonable to expect that the males are generally taller than the females, though, so Hagrid may be short for a male half-giant, but that seemed too tentative to add to my answer

Comment: "Then Harry saw a shining, high-heeled black shoe emerging from the inside of the carriage - a shoe the size of a child's sled - followed, almost immediately, by the largest woman he had seen in his life. ... Harry had only ever seen one person as large as this woman in his life, and that was Hagrid; he doubted whether there was an inch difference in their heights. Yet somehow - maybe simply because he was used to Hagrid - this woman ... seemed even more unnaturally large."

Comment: @DVK we in the United Kingdom have a long and proud history of beloved childrens literature which is actually really quite disturbing if an adult looks at it too long or too hard. Reference anything by Roald Dahl for a start.